# Can I display an alternative element to the flash element in my website?

Tags: css, html, flash

I built a website and I have some flash elements. how can I recognize if the user's browser support flash and display new element if it is not?

Comment: Is your alternative element (to the Flash) going to be just as interactive? e.g. HTML5.  If so, why not go straight to HTML5?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`SWFObject`](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) which is a javascript library allowing you to play well between JS & flash and giving you some opportunities for fallback.

For example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">  
    <head>    
        <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>    
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>        
        <script type="text/javascript">    
            swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");    
        </script>  
    </head>  
    <body>    
        <div id="myContent">      
            <p>Alternative content</p>    
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```